# Greatest coefficient of $x$ in expansion of $(1+2x)^8$

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, alternative-proof, binomial-theorem

> If the sum of the coefficients in the expansion of $(1+2x)^n$ is 6561, then what is  the value of the greatest coefficient in the expansion?

**Solution**

*Standard Result*:If $n$ is even positive integer then the greatest coefficient in the Binomial Expansion of $(x+a)^n$ is ${n\choose \frac{n}{2}}$

Sum of the Coefficients in the expansion of $(1+2x)^n=(1+2\times1)^n=3^n$.But it is given that Sum of the Coefficients in the expansion of $(1+2x)^n$ is 6561.

So,$3^n=6561=2^{11}\implies n=8$

Using the Standard result,we get **Greatest Coefficient** in the expansion of $(1+2x)^8=2^8(x+\frac{1}{2})$ is $2^8 \times {8\choose \frac{8}{2}}$=$2^8 \times {8\choose 4}=2^8 \times \frac{8\times 7\times 6 \times 5}{4\times3\times2\times1}=17920$

But the Correct answer is $1792$.

Please point out my mistake.

Thank you

Comment: The *standard result* is weird. It may not hold for $a \ne 1$, consider the simple case $(x+3)^2$. Perhaps by "coefficient" they meant the coefficient of $x^ka^{n-k}$.

Comment: @player3236:You seems correct!! In my text book it is given that the greatest coefficient  in the binomial expoansion of $(x+a)^n$  is $n \choose \frac{n}{2},$given that $n\in 2\mathbb Z$

Comment: @player3236:Means standard result holds for $(1+x)^n$ only!! Right?

Comment: Indeed. There could be context missing, or the textbook omitted the contribution of $a$. So for your question you need to list out all the $\binom n k 2^k$, or at least for $k \ge \frac82 = 4$.

Comment: @player3236:gotcha !! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of $x$ in $(1+2x)^8$ is $^8C_r 2^r$ -- not simply $^8C_r$. So it's maximum won't occur at usual maximum of binomial coefficients alone (which occurs at $r=n/2$).

One instead has to maximize the general term as
$$ \dfrac{\text{coefficient of } T_{r+1}}{\text{coefficient of } T_r} > 1  $$

and solve for $r$.

I got this way that $^8C_6 2^6$ is the largest coefficient. Indeed $$ ^8C_6 2^6 = 1792$$